# Передать с формы данные в поток?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть поток, работает все нормально. Но надо с формы передать данные в поток

```
string url = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { textBox.Text; }));
```

Была идея такая, но не помогло, видимо работает в обратную сторону из потока на форму.

Подскажите как передать данные, в поток с формы.

Comment: А почему поток, а не Task? Что именно вы делаете в этом потоке?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите. Вы должны сначала прочитать данные, которые есть в контролах, в UI-потоке. А затем отправить их в другой поток. Сейчас для выполнения кода в отдельном потоке такого принято использовать `Task`. Таким образом, ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
// UI-поток
string text = textbox.Text;
Task.Run(() => ProcessText(text));
// метод ProcessText будет выполнен в пуле потоков
```

---

А что делать, если поток *уже* есть, и в него нужно доставить сообщение? В любом случае для этого в потоке должен бежать какой-то цикл сообщений. В WinForms удобного цикла сообщений нет, но можно одолжить у WPF. Для этого подключите сборку `WindowsBase`, и заведите диспетчер.

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

// ...

Dispatcher dispatcher = null;

// запускаем поток
var t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();

void ThreadProc()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("bg thread started");
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    Dispatcher.Run();
    Debug.WriteLine("bg thread finished");
}
```

Теперь в этот поток можно доставлять сообщения:

```
string text = textBox.Text;
dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ProcessInThread(text)));
```

Когда поток больше не нужен, его можно закрыть:

```
dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

---

Окей, доступ к переменной `dispatcher` надо бы по-хорошему синхронизировать. Не делаю этого, чтобы не утяжелять код.